# Deep linking to iOS app through Facebook share

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

Currently is it possible to do a deep link on a Facebook share post? Here is the use case I'm trying to implement:

1. I go to a post on my website: http://www.helloworld.com/share-this-post.html and use FB share to share the link.
2. I open the iOS Facebook app on my phone and click on the link I just shared.
3. Then if I have the native HelloWorld iOS app installed on my phone, Facebook will open up my native app instead of opening the link in a webview. Else it will take me to the app store to download my native app.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz yeah, FB recently launched a feature called [Applinks](http://applinks.org/) which lets you set a series of meta tags on your page that lets the FB app know how to deep link to your app based on a url.

Comment: What if I'm sharing with whatsapp or imessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic idea here is a URL Scheme that you need to create. When a user does the actions necessary to open your app send them to this URL -> which opens your app or takes them to the app store to purchase your app.

Do a quick google search on how to create a URL scheme, its quite simple.

Does this answer your question?